# Does Html.RenderAction create a separate request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I'm not seeing any extra requests in Fiddler when I have a view that makes `RenderAction` calls. Is it because it isn't a separate web request, per say, it's all done internally when the controller is rendering its view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RenderAction` simply invokes the given action on a controller.  The result of that action will be written to the current page that's being requested. It does not force the client to make additional requests.

For more info, see Phil Haack's post about [Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).